# Windows 7 - Group Policy - Allow RDP Credentials to be Saved

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, group-policy, credentials

Im trying to use RDP and save my credentials in a file so I dont have to entire it each time I connect.

I remember doing it before and it involved changing a group policy setting. What exactly do I need to change in Group Policy within Windows 7 in the host & client machines to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found a link that solved this problem:

http://www.perceptible.net/post/2009/02/03/How-To-Enable-Use-of-Saved-Credentials-with-Remote-Desktop-to-Almost-Fully-Authenticated-Machines.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Answered link doesn't work anymore.

[This link might help](http://blog.ronnypot.nl/?p=247), instead.

Start local group policy editor, `start – run – gpedit.msc
Go to Local Computer Policy –> Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> System –> Credentials Delegation`
Edit “`Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication`”
Enable the policy, click Show and enter the value “`TERMSRV/*`” into the list.

[image]

Do the same thing for the following policies:

- `Allow Delegating Saved Credentials`
- `Allow Delegating Default Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication`
- `Allow Delegating Default Credentials`